# Can't get email while parsing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new at scraping and parsing and I don't know what to do with the next problem. I need to scrape email from many pages. [For example](http://findyourvacationhome.com/find.php?property=5068927%22For%20example%22)

The part of the code where email is:

```
<tr><td>Email:</td><td width="10"></td><td><script>var ylhrfq = "&#121;&#112;&#114;";var bdnd = "&#97;&#105;&#108;";var byil = "&#115;&#116;&#46;&#99;";var bwdbdf = "&#97;&#103;&#101;&#64;";var dqiex = "&#46;&#99;";var pner = "&#111;&#109;";var qkfow = "&#103;&#109;";var azzl = "&#105;&#101;";var hgcr = "&#110;&#46;&#112;&#108;";var link = byil + ylhrfq + azzl + hgcr + bwdbdf + qkfow + bdnd + dqiex + pner;var text = link;document.write('<a href="mailto:'+link+'"  />'+text+'</a>');</script></td></tr>
```

Is it possible to grab this email with BF ? If yes how can I do this?

Win7, Python3, BeautifulSoup

Comment: I've got an answer here: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485389/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-email-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It seems the email address is hiden in original html and generated by javascript code. With `python2`, `requests`, `js2py`, `BeautifulSoup4`, I finally got the correct email address, hopefully this is what you wanted.

```
import bs4
import requests
import subprocess
import js2py
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

html = requests.get('http://findyourvacationhome.com/find.php?property=5068927').content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
raw_script = soup.find_all('table')[6].find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[2].script.contents[0]

script = raw_script.replace("""var text = link;document.write('<a href="mailto:'+link+'"  />'+text+'</a>');""", """""")
result = js2py.eval_js(script)
htmlparser = HTMLParser()
result = htmlparser.unescape(result)

print(result)
```

I did it in 4 steps:

1. get the html of the web page with `requests`
2. use `BeautifulSoup4` to parse html code and get the javascript code which used to generate the email
3. use `js2py` execute the js code and get the result.
4. escape the string with `HTMLParser`

Comment: realhu, thank you, bit I've meant to scrape email from webpage not from saved html.

Comment: it it is from a web page, you can get the html content with ```requests```, something like ```html=requests.get('http://example.com').content```, others should be the same

Comment: realhu, please, take a look at the part of the html code I posted. Your code  doesn't extract email because there is JS code.

Comment: @GiveItAwayNow Yap. I finally got it and finally work it out, hopefully this is what you wanted.

Comment: realhu, thank you. Unfortunately for some reason the code doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post the result? Make sure you are using python2.7 and BeautifulSoup4

Comment: I'm using Python3, maybe the problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the parsed html. The source itself only contains placeholders and scripts. In PowerShell I would run this to get the email:

```
$t = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://findyourvacationhome.com/find.php?property=5068927"
$t.Links | Where-Object { $_.href -match 'mailto' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty outertext
```

Comment: Frode F., I need to parse a lot of pages, I mean I have to do it with Python script.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have used the powershell tag. Don't know Python.